# Is it possible to use Web Deploy from Visual Studio Online?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, one-click-web-publishing

I would like to build in Visual Studio Online and then Web Publish to Amazon.

Is this possible? Or does it only publish to Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran MSBuild with the following parameters added...

```
/P:DeployOnBuild=True
/P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
/P:DeployIISAppPath=MyWebsite
/P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
/P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc
/P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
/P:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://DOMAIN/MsDeploy.axd
/P:UserName=User1
/P:Password=******
```

Comment: However only cowboys deploy directly from checkin to Production with no checks! Professionals create a release pipeline with automated tests and gates to help minimise production issues.

Comment: @MrHinsh What is a gate?

Comment: A gate would be any sort of test or measure for moving forward. Sometimes an approval, but more often a set of automated checks.

Answer (score 2):

It publishes to wherever you like.

Use the PowerShell, Batch, or ShellScript task to deploy to whatever system you like in whatever way that you want.

Better yet, create a professional release pipeline with release management and deploy to many environments.

Comment: Even easier, see my answer.